# Better way than using multiple if

Tags: javascript

I have a simple problem: I need to roll two sets of dice. For each number possible in the first roll, there are a set of conditionals that I then check against the second roll. The conditionals for each roll are different.

The problem, to me, is that something like this repeated roughly thirty times seems like a gross thing to stick in my code:

```
    if (roll == 3) {
        if (secondRoll < 5) {
           do this
        }
        else if (secondRoll > 5 && secondRoll < 10) {
           do this
        }
        else {
           do this
        }
    }

    if ...... and so on
```

So what do I do? Is there a more elegant way to do this? I've thought about something like this:

```
    class Result {
        constructor(firstRoll, secondRollMin, secondRollMax, output) {
            this.firstRoll;
            this.secondRollMin;
            this.secondRollMax;
            this.output;
        }
    }
```

and then checking the rolls against matching properties in a set of objects, but I'm not sure that's honestly any better. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of dice is that if you check for <10? Can it result in an 8? Also, why do you check for the second roll to be between 5 and 10? Is it always the same check for second roll?

Comment: I'm rolling three six sided dice for each roll. It isn't always the same set of checks for the second roll. They are different, depending on the number in the first roll.

Comment: We need to know those details to be able to help

Comment: `secondRoll` is the second die only? Not clear on when that number can go above 6.

Comment: Well, we need to know the rules in order to create a system to apply them.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small improvement, but you only need to check the upper bound of the range in each subsequence `else if`:

```
if (roll == 3) {
    if (secondRoll < 5) {
       do this
    }
    else if (secondRoll < 10) {  // secondRoll must be >= 5 already
       do this
    }
    else {
       do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Switch` to simplify

```
switch (roll) {
    case 1-4: 
        // Do something.
        break;
    case 5-8: 
        // Do something.
        break;
    case 9-11: 
        // Do something.
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a key for the combination and a bit simpler `if/else`? You could combine any combination that has the same action.

```js
const combo = `${roll}-${secondRoll}`;

if (['1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '3-4', '3-5', '3-6'].includes(combo) {
  // Do this
} else if (['1-4', '1-5', '1-6', '3-1', '3-2', '3-3'].includes(combo) {
  // Do this
// ...
} else if (['6-4', '6-5', '6-6'].includes(combo) {
  // Do this
}
```

Or create a `switch/case`:

```js
const combo = `${roll}-${secondRoll}`;

switch (combo) {
  case '1-1':
  case '1-2':
  case '1-3':
  case '3-4':
  case '4-5':
  case '5-6':
    // Do this
    break;
  case '1-4':
  case '1-5':
  case '1-6':
  case '3-1':
  case '4-2':
  case '5-3':
    // Do this
    break;
  // ...
  case '6-4':
  case '6-5':
  case '6-6':
    // Do this
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a mixture of if, else and switch blocks. You can use different methods to call based on the first roll. A switch statement is usually more efficient than a set of nested ifs.

```
class Result {
        constructor(firstRoll, secondRollMin, secondRollMax, output) {
            this.firstRoll;
            this.secondRollMin;
            this.secondRollMax;
            this.output;


            switch(firstRoll){
                case 1:
                    this.output = oneToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin)
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.output = twoToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMax)
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.output = threeToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMax)
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.output = fourToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMax)
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.output = fiveToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMax)
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.output = sixToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMax)
                    break;
            }
        }

          static String oneToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
            String result = ""

            if (secondRollMin < 5) {
               result = "My result"
            }
            else if (secondRollMin < 10) {
                result = "My result 2"
            }

            return result
        } 

         static String twoToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
            String result = ""
            if (secondRollMin < 5) {
               result = "My result"
            }
            else if (secondRollMin < 10) {
                result = "My result 2"
            }
            return result
        } 

         static String threeToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
          // Same as above...
        } 

        static Stfing fourToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
          // Same as above...
        } 

        static String fiveToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
          // Same as above...
        } 

        static String sixToXTime(secondRollMin,secondRollMin) {
          // Same as above...
        } 

    }
```